# catch click event on activity when youtube API is playing

Tags: java, android, api, youtube

i'm using youtube API for android and playing youtube on all the screen in android native.
the youtube componnent is inside Relative view. if id don't initilize the youtube view i get the click event , but if i initilize  it , i can't catch any event.
is there a global touch event on activity that i can detect? that is not related to view?

this is example of the fullscreen activity demo with the youtube component as content

XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context="com.fullscreen.test.testfullscreen.FullscreenActivity">

    <!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc. -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:text="@string/dummy_content"
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/black_overlay"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dummy_button"

                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/dummy_button" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

activity:

```
package XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
//import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
//import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import com.examples.youtubeapidemo.R;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;
import XXXXXXXXXXXxX.playlist.MoviesListHandler;
import XXXXXXXXXXXXX.android.view.LayoutObjsList;

/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 */
public class FullscreenActivity extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity {
    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * Some older devices needs a small delay between UI widget updates
     * and a change of the status and navigation bar.
     */
    private static final int UI_ANIMATION_DELAY = 300;
    private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    private View mContentView;
    private final Runnable mHidePart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed removal of status and navigation bar

            // Note that some of these constants are new as of API 16 (Jelly Bean)
            // and API 19 (KitKat). It is safe to use them, as they are inlined
            // at compile-time and do nothing on earlier devices.
            mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        }
    };
    private View mControlsView;
    private final Runnable mShowPart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed display of UI elements
            /*
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.show();
            }
            */
            mControlsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };
    private boolean mVisible;
    private final Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hide();
        }
    };
    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */
    private final View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
    {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_youtube);
        YouTubePlayerView fullscreen_content = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
        fullscreen_content.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
        mVisible = true;
        mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);


        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggle();
            }
        });

        // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
        // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
        // while interacting with the UI.
        findViewById(R.id.dummy_button).setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }

    private void toggle() {
        if (mVisible) {
            hide();
        } else {
            show();
        }
    }

    private void hide() {

        // Hide UI first
        /*
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();

        }
         */
        mControlsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mVisible = false;

        // Schedule a runnable to remove the status and navigation bar after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mShowPart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHidePart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private void show() {
        // Show the system bar
        mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        mVisible = true;

        // Schedule a runnable to display UI elements after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHidePart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mShowPart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis)
    {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }

    @Override
    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

    }
}
```